A Set of Maps which act Transitively on all Affine Partitions of $\mathbb F_p^n.$
Consider the set of all partitions of $\mathbb F_2^n$ such that each subset in the partition is an affine space of dimension $n/2$. Does there exist a family of maps which act transitively on this set? I know that full rank linear maps send one affine partition to another affine partition, but I am not sure if the set of invertible linear maps act transitively on this set.
Thanks for any help!

It makes no difference to my partial answer, but is the question about a general prime $p$ or about $p=2$ in particular (as somewhat indicated in the question body)?

Thank you for your partial answer. Our situation was for the case when $p = 2$ but I ended up writing it for a general prime $p$. I was hoping there would be some maps which act transitively because I need a way to getting to a uniform random partition after starting at a given partition. However finding such a family of maps seems like a difficult problem!

The question is somewhat subtle, and I don't know the full solution. The point of posting this is that I can answer the question in the last sentence in the negative when $n\ge4$.
Let $G=\mathrm{Aff}(n,\Bbb{F}_2)$ be the group of affine transformation. That is, with $V=\Bbb{F}_2^n$, the trasnformations $T$ from $V$ to itself of the form
$$T(x)=L(x)+y,$$
where $L\in GL_n(\Bbb{F}_p)$ is an invertible linear transformation, and $y\in V$ is a fixed vector. If $W\subseteq V$ is any subspace of dimension $n/2$, and $T\in G$ is as above, then $T$ maps an affine subspace $W+z$ to the affine subspace
$L(W)+T(z)$. Consequently $T$ maps a partition of $V$ of the prescribed type to some other such partition.
However, $G$ does not act transitively on the set of all possible affine partitions. If $W\subset V$ is any vector subspace of $V$ such that $\dim W=n/2$, then its cosets $W+y$, $y\in V$, form an affine partition of $V$. Let's
call such partitions coset partitions (don't know if there is a commonly used term for such partitions, I simply made it up). Then the above affine transformation $T$ maps such a partition into the partition consisting of the cosets of $L(W)$. In other words, $G$ always maps a coset partition into another coset partition.
My main claim then follows if I can show that there exists affine partitions other than coset partitions. To that end I need to assume that $n\ge4$. This is easy, because there's a lot of elbow room in $V$. Let $k=(n/2)+1<n$, and let us fix a subspace $U\subset V$ of dimension $k$. We can first partition $V$ into cosets of
$U$, and as $k<n$ there will be more than a single coset. Because $k\ge2$, $U$
has at least two different subspaces $W_1$ and $W_2$ of dimension $n/2$. We can then further partition at least one coset of $U$ into cosets of $W_1$, and the other cosets of $U$ into cosets of $W_2$. It is then clear that the resulting partition of $V$ is still affine, but it is not a coset partition.

Observe that when $n=2$ there is no wiggle room. Every affine partition will then be a coset partition simply because cosets of two distinct 1-dimensional subspaces intersect non-trivially (two non-parallel lines of the plane intersect at a single point). Because the general linear group acts transitively on the collection of 1-dimensional subspaces, it will act transitively on the collection of affine partitions as well (with or without the translation by $y$ part).

I don't know if we can form a bigger group of  permutations of $V$ acting transitively on the collection of all the affine partitions. I don't know if all the affine partitions are gotten by splitting $V$ into cosets of smaller and smaller subspaces (ending at dimension $n/2$).
